# How to test that the method of an instance has been called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value=1):
        self.value = value
        self.destructive_stuff()

    def destructive_stuff(self):
        print("Running destructive commands on the host...")

    def compute_value(self):
        return self.value * 10

def main():
    sample = MyClass(value=5)
    print(f"Computed value: {sample.compute_value()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to test the `main()` function. Specifically, I want to check that the `compute_value()` method has been called. I'm using a Mock since I don't want a real instance of `MyClass` initialized, because it would run `destructive_stuff()`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import my_sample

class TestPieq(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_sample.MyClass")
    def test_called(self, mock_myclass):
        my_sample.main()
        mock_myclass.compute_value.assert_called()
```

When I run this, though, it fails:

```
$ python3 -m unittest tests.py
Computed value: <MagicMock name='MyClass().compute_value()' id='140298914799936'>
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_called (tests.TestSample)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1379, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "/tmp/pieq/tests.py", line 9, in test_called
    mock_myclass.compute_value.assert_called()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 898, in assert_called
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'compute_value' to have been called.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I target the method directly in the `patch` directive, my test passes... but it uses the real class, so it calls the `destructive_stuff()` method!

```
class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_sample.MyClass.compute_value")
    def test_called(self, mock_myclass_compute):
        my_sample.main()
        mock_myclass_compute.assert_called()
```

```
$ python3 -m unittest tests.py
Running destructive commands on the host...
Computed value: <MagicMock name='compute_value()' id='140289139827584'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

How to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a method of an instance that you're testing, and the instance is created by calling the class, you should put parentheses after the mocked class to obtain the mocked instance for testing.

Change:

```
mock_myclass.compute_value.assert_called()
```

to:

```
mock_myclass().compute_value.assert_called()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion this morning and I must have messed up something, cause it didn't work... and I just tried again after publishing my findings, and now it works!

Comment: Glad to know it works for you. Can you mark this answer accepted if you find it to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by asserting the call on an instance of the mocked class rather than on the class itself:

```py
class TestSample(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_sample.MyClass")
    def test_called(self, mock_myclass):
        my_sample.main()
        instance = mock_myclass.return_value
        instance.compute_value.assert_called()
```

It now passes!